# Shell:nested for loop

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, nested-loops

Somehow  in the following script, value of `$i`
is not expanded on line 3. Any idea why?

```
for i in `cat test.txt`
do
        for j in `find . -name $i`
        do
                echo $j
        done
done
```

Comment: @dharm0us - what is inside "test.txt" ? if find does not return any matches, simply quote it `for j in `find . -name "*$i*"`

Comment: @dharm0us: Are you sure that the problem is the expansion? I tried it and it worked correctly. Put that script in a file and add `#!/bin/bash -x` at the top of it to see what's going on.

Comment: @Thomas, no error message, simply no output

Comment: @ajreal - test.txt has file names, one name per line. find does return matches for the file names, when executed on command line.

Comment: @Alberto : $ ./test.sh
++ cat test.txt
+ for i in '`cat test.txt`'
++ find . -name $'CityForest.fla\r'

Comment: @dharm0us: is the script executable ? at least 744

Comment: @ajreal, yes it's executable.

Comment: @dharm0us - clueless, never use cygwin before, try this `cat test.txt|xargs` ?

Comment: @ajreal, yes it's something to do with cygwin. I tried the same script on a linux box, it works.

Comment: Ok, got it finally. I need to convert the files from dos to unix format, using d2u command. It works after that. d2u test.txt;d2u test.sh;./test.sh

Comment: @ajreal, can you post it as an answer, so that I accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in `cat test.txt | sed -e "s/\r//g"`; do find -name $i; done
```

big question: **cygwin support sed?**

or cygwin

```
d2u test.txt; for i in `cat test.txt`; do find -name $i; done
```

or linux

```
dos2unix test.txt; for i in `cat test.txt`; do find -name $i; done
```

Answer (score 2):

After you fix the line endings:

```
xargs --arg-file test.text -I % find . -name "%"
```

No need for nested loops.